# What is "right of way"?

Tags: contemporary-latin, modern-life, traffic

What is "right of way" (in the sense of being allowed to go first in traffic) in Latin?
Is there by any chance an attested expression for essentially the same thing?
I would like a phrase suitable for modern traffic.

Forming verbal expressions like "is allowed to go first" is simpler, but that is not what I'm after.
The best thing I could come up with is *libertas praeeundi*, but I would not be surprised if there is a more natural way to put it.
Perhaps *ius vehendi*?

Comment: Probably *ius* with whatever term Modern Latin has designated for an intransitive "drive."

Comment: In the sport of fencing, there is also a term "right of way." I wonder if there is also translation for this that may be similar. Probably not, but this question reminded me of that phrase.

Comment: Terms for 'give way' are easier to find; e.g. *cedere viam.* Perhaps *tenere viam,* or *viam jure tenere;* 'to hold the way by right.'

Comment: @SamK The term has several different uses. That's why I was specific about what I want to translate. I don't think any single phrase can (or should) capture them all.

Comment: Nor do I! I was just thinking about a definition I knew of that phrase, so I was just making an only somewhat related comment. :)

Comment: Roman Law knows of _ius eundi_ and _ius agendi_, which are more like a guarantee of the right of free passage (if necessary, through somebody's land). This is not, of course, the same as having precedence in traffic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly, *ius* indicates the right to take some sort of action, so I should think that either *ius itineris* ('right of route') or *ius transitus* ('right of crossing') would be generally suitable as a traffic instruction (and, being more direct and powerful, preferable to using *facultas*, another possibility).

For the party conceding right of way, *transitum dare* (Livy 21.20 and Caesar BG 1.8) is probably all right.

Comment: I just did a quick search on the _Adumbratio Lexici Anglico-Latini_, which returned the result ius eundi, as well as ius itineris, so that is also a possibility.

Comment: The Livy and Caesar examples furnished here make *ius transitum* very attractive. Tough to choose which is better.

Comment: For myself, I think I'd pick _ius itineris_, 'right to follow the route'. _Ius transitus_ might better be the 'right to cross', as on a pedestrian crossing.

Comment: Those are good suggestions! I especially like *ius transitus*, especially when one has the right of way to cross a lane or something else. It's good to know that *ius* is the right "right" word.

Comment: @C.M.Weiner  Yes, so it is, but _transitus_ is here a 4th declension genitive.

Comment: Ah OK, I was thinking participle on analogy with ius naturale.

Comment: @C. M. Weiner Everybody does it at some time or other. Remember Horace : _et idem / indignor quandoque bonus dormitat Homerus_ (AP l. 358) and laugh it off!

Comment: Everybody makes mistakes, for sure (relook at my name, for example), but I'd actually make the argument that the preferable usage is with an adjective or participle. Consider the *ius publicum*, *ius civile*, *ius praediatorium*, *iura communia*, *iura coniugialia* (Ov. Met. 6). Where you have a noun in the genitive, e.g. *ius gentium* or *ius adoptionis* either it's of the group (the former) or doesn't have a great adjective (the latter). This isn't to say that *ius transitus* is wrong, no, not saying that, but I think were it coined by a Roman, it probably would have been *ius transitum*.